# NSURLResponse returns nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been using NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: method. But, I am not able to get responce. every time httpResponse returns nil.

```
NSString *str=@" http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bapunagar,%20Ahmedabad,%20Gujarat&destination=CG%20Road,%20Sattar%20Taluka%20Society,%20Usman%20Pura,%20Ahmedabad,%20Gujarat&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=transit&departure_time=1343605500&language=ar";
    str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {
         NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
         NSLog(@"%@",httpResponse);
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil && [httpResponse statusCode] == 200)
         {
             NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
             NSLog(@"%@",json);

         }}];
```

what is wrong in this?
help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You have an extra space at the start of that URL. Remove that extra space.
2. You are calling `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` on a URL that has already been percent escaped. Remove this call to `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

Comment: thnaks but i am not able to get proper json

Comment: What do you mean by proper Json? your json response has special characters? hit the URL on browser and check, its the same.

Comment: @Sunnyshah When I do those two changes, I get a response that is successfully parsed by `NSJSONSerialization`. Please clarify by what you mean by not "proper json".